# Neural network does not train

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am playing around with tensorflow/keras a little and tried to create a small neural network that trains on some random data I produced. However, no matter what I change about the size of the dataset or the layers, I always come to get an accuracy of 0. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

numbers = np.random.randint(0, 101, (1000000,3))
labels = np.array([0 if x[0] < 50 and x[1] < 50 and x[2] < 50 else
                 1 if x[0] >= 50 and x[1] < 50 and x[2] < 50 else
                 2 if x[0] < 50 and x[1] >= 50 and x[2] < 50 else 
                 3 if x[0] < 50 and x[1] < 50 and x[2] >= 50 else
                 4 if x[0] >= 50 and x[1] >= 50 and x[2] < 50 else
                 5 if x[0] >= 50 and x[1] < 50 and x[2] >= 50 else
                 6 if x[0] < 50 and x[1] >= 50 and x[2] >= 50 else
                 7 for x in numbers])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy'])

BATCH_SIZE = 5000
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((numbers, labels))
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().shuffle(len(numbers)).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 10, steps_per_epoch=len(numbers)/BATCH_SIZE)
```

I expect it to somewhat get an accuracy that is better than chance (which would be 0.125), but I always get 0.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the loss function 'categorical_crossentropy' is wrong in my situation; changing it to 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' boosted my accuracy to ~78%, so I would guess this whole thing is solved. But if there are other problems with my code, please comment, as I am still new and learning. :)